# Problem rigging weight paint

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm new here and a beginner of blender.
i have a problem with rigging, some parts of my mesh deform. i'm italian so sorry if i speak very badly.
that's the problem:
[image]

[image]

the back is deforming when i rotate the on the x axis the leg. 
the model is only one mesh, i don't know if that can be a problem, the piece of armor on the leg is connected to the back.

sorry for the question or my writing, i'm following a lot of tutorials but i cannot resolve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There can be several reasons... maybe, in the modifiers panel, put the Armature above the Subsurf, and in the Armature modifier, enable the Preserve Volume option? You can also share your file so that we can see.

Comment: also, maybe your mesh needs some additional edge loops, or the weight painting is bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is my opinion:

- First you need to put the Armature modifier above the Subsurf modifier, and enable the Preserve Volume option.
- You should add a little more weight on the butt for the leg, you'll see that it works better when you rotate the leg
- Maybe add a hip bone and weight paint to add a little bit more precision in the mesh control?

[image]

Comment: ok, i'll try! thank u so much! only one question: i'm following a tutorial and the guy deleted the bone from hip and leg. but in it's case that part is covered by a skirt. I have misunderstood

Comment: well, you could delete the hip but I think it will give more precision and solve some problems, by the way if you add a hip bone, it's mostly this bone that must influence the butt, give less influence to the leg... anyway, each case is different, you have to make some tests

Comment: sorry @moonboots i have another question/problem: to animate it the body must be there in full or the parts covered by the suit can I remove them? I'm having problems because of the lack of body parts I believe. when I move the arm forward, for example, it mixes with the suit.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncKqy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncKqy.png) both the neck and the arms are not complete because covered, is this a problem? or should I set up differently? legs and sit I solved

Comment: if you want to delete any influence of the bone on the mesh you can use Weight Paint or you can go on the Vertex Group list: vertex groups have been created on your mesh when parenting and they are named by your bones name. To remove some parts of the mesh from some bone influence, select these vertices, then select the name of the bone in the Vertex Groups list, then click Remove (or Assign if you want to assign), you can also change the influence ratio below the list. Other functions on the right of the list (available when you click on the down arrow), I don't know if that's useful? Tell me

Comment: thanks, I knew I could do that. I try to move the bones of the arm a little to the outside and I see what happens. maybe so I can do it.

but normally the covered body parts can be left as in the screenshot I showed before? I refer to arms and neck

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, if Weight Paint or Vertex Groups assignment doesn't fix your problem you can try to change your bone organisation or maybe change the mesh... for example it looks like your arm is not attached to your shoulder, why that? please explain your problem again, and share your file with you want

Comment: yes, attach the shoulders to the torso and attach the arms to the shoulders! Rigging is complicated and can take a lot of time. The forearm/wrist is particularly tricky, you need to segment the forearm and add a Copy Rotation with the hand as target, so that the wrist rotate smoothly, also in Pose mode there's an Inverse Kinematics in the Bone menu that allows to constrain the arms movements and that's very helpful, it took me time to realize

Comment: copy rotation forearm/hand like this? https://image.ibb.co/dDqjcT/rotation_forearm_arm.png

Comment: yes, it will allow your forearm to follow the rotation of your hand, but the Space should be in Local Space > Local Space - and by the way, your forearm should also have an Inverse Kinematics constraint

Comment: it's already local space > local space. now i search about the inverse kinematics constraint xD I have already done damage going to guess

Comment: Oh sorry I meant it should be Pose Space > Pose Space, but make some tries...

Comment: however before you told me about segment the forearm and add a copyrotation, i did the second (add copy rotation) but i dind't segment the forearm. now i'm looking a tutorial where the guy segment the forearm... it's okay how i did it or not? xD also can i add the IKc after the model doesn't deform in the pose mode? I would like to fix that first. for now i completed and fixed the hands, i think now they are fne. instead the forearm moves much when i roteate the hand doh..this the file if u have time http://www.mediafire.com/file/n80xk337rk7yz0f/rifatto%20arma.blend what u think?

Comment: hello, it's hard to help, the rotation constraint of your armature is indeed what I meant but your armature lacks a lot of many things like controllers and pole targets, you should check blender character rigging on youtube, you'll find a lot of tutorials, none of them are really complete on this topic, but some are good, and if you try a lot of them, it will help you to understand the process and make your own idea about how to do it efficiently. Dig into it and come back later to ask me some questions... I'm going to share an armature that I consider as advanced in few hours if you want

Comment: if you can share it I would be useful, at least I get an idea.
at this point I end up seeing the tutorial I had started trying to figure out what's wrong

Comment: I think this one is rather correct, didn't put the face bones though, it's a basic one, feel free to ask me question if you need: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49921

Comment: why the legs and arms doesn't move?  I can not move them forward.

Comment: because they have an IK constraint, you have to use their controllers to make them move, example, the bone called IK_hand_L

Comment: ok. can you sugest me a video tutorial or other where you learn this?

Comment: I've learnt through several tutorials, because not one was enough to understand, so type "rigging character blender" in Youtube, then try several, take notes, try your own armature without tutorial, then come back to tutorials, etc. It's not as complicated as it seems, you just need to understand some principles like IK bones, and some tricks to fix some problems like the twist of the wrist, etc... if you have some questions, ask me!

Comment: ok the last question then review when I "finished" xD all this should then be added in unity to make the demo of a video game. I know it's stupid to ask this, but am I proceeding in the right direction you know? I would not find myself doing things (even if I think they are necessary) useless to reach that goal

Comment: I guess yes, you have to rig the character as best as you can to make the animations you need, so you need to learn rigging. I don't know Unity though...

Comment: thx. I'm doing everything over again and I have another problem, when I'm in poses mode and rotates certain bones, the mesh moves very little. yet I redid everything the same, I just added more mesh deformer and I did not remove the bones as you advised me. what's wrong? .. http://www.mediafire.com/file/jsgig1jv0dxgd6a/armatura++prova+4.blend

Comment: hello, yes that's weird, I'm going to try to find what's wrong, anyway you can deparent the object, then parent again and it works (maybe it needs some adjustments though)

Comment: by the way, for all the bones that are not supposed to have any weight (for example targets, pole targets, root bone, etc.), think about declicking the Deform option in the Properties > Bone menu, before you parent the object to the armature

Comment: if you reparent it, it works, so the interesting thing should be to know how you first parented it, because I don't know what's happening

Comment: oh you've created a vertex group called Armature, if you delete it everything works, so I'll try to find out how it was playing on the armature...

Comment: i changed the parent type object of the character from object to armature. now it works. I did not remember doing it before https://image.ibb.co/faNdRo/armatura_prova_4.png

Comment: ok there must has been a conflict

Comment: In the armature I've sent you, I've just realized, in Properties > Bone > Inverse Kinematics, that the Rotation is off for the Y axis, so you should switch it on and limit its amount of degrees (for example -90° / 90°) so that you allow your wrist to move the forearm (or the Copy Rotation of the forearm would be useless)